# stop child window reloading even when parent window has reloaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent-child

I have this child window and a condition which prevents the window reloading if 'send' is clicked again while window is still open with variable 'myStatus' equal to 'processing'. The problem is if the child window is opened and then the parent page is refreshed and 'send' is clicked again, the childPage variable is lost and it allows the child page to reload. is there a way around this problem? Thanks.

```
var childPage = null;

$('#send').click(function(){

    if(childPage && !childPage.closed && childPage.myStatus == "processing"){
      alert('child window is open and processing');
    }else{
     childPage = window.open("test.html","send","width = 300,height=300");
}):
```

Comment: Is stopping the parentpage from reloading an option? You could use `onbeforeunload` on parentpage to conditionally check if `childPage.myStatus == "processing"`

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but no, in fact the whole reason why the page opens as a child is to give the user the option to browse while the child page is processing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had same problem

I solved it using two way communication

if user refresh parent page send this information to child window. 
child window will run a timer which will keep checking if parent page is reloaded.
once parent page is reloaded create reference of child window in parent

Code:

in parentWindow

```
 window.onbeforeunload =function (){
  childPage.reconnect();
}

window.saveChildReference =function (ref){
  childPage = ref;
}
```

in child window

```
window.reconnect = function(){
     var i =0;
   var timer = setInterval(function(){
    i++;
        if(window.opener && window.opener.saveChildReference ){
               window.opener.saveChildReference(window);
             clearTimeout(timer );
         }

        if(i > 100){
         clearTimeout(timer );// stop trying as parent may be closed.
      }

   }, 100);

};
```

Comment: a fantastic solution, thank you for sharing the benefit of your experience :)